# Fragment instance retain in android

Tags: android

in main activiy i call a fragment and in fragment iam displaying a progress dialog in async task now my question is when orientation change my progress dialog restart and i want it retain its state iam using a retainInstance(true) but its not working.
 my fragment code is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        if(pDialog!=null)
        {
            pDialog.show();
        }

    }


}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("status", "ok");

}


public void showProgress()
{

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMax(900000000);
    pDialog.show();
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    proceed=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    proceed.setOnClickListener(this);
    return  view;

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{

    new inner().execute();
}
class inner extends AsyncTask
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgress();

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
    {
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        {
            pDialog.incrementProgressBy(i);
            for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
            {
                k=k+j;

            }
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("enter here");
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }



}

@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onStop() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if (pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

}
```

Comment: Is that the code of your activity or of your fragment?

Comment: this is my fragment code

Comment: I can't see where you call setretaininstance(true)

Comment: check that oncreate method i edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your current progress in onDetach and use it again in onAttach. Example:

```
    private ProgressDialog buildDialog() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setProgress(currentProgress);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    return progressDialog;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    attached = true;
    if (taskStarted) {
        progressDialog = this.buildDialog();
        progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(messageId));
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        currentProgress = progressDialog.getProgress();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
    }
    attached = false;
}
```

Comment: actually behind his i want to conect with internet so i want my all data retain its state event connection to internet

Comment: This is an other question so please open a new questions. Upvote and accept this response.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example of this the other day. Here you go

https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/11368894